# Hardware buttons is not clickable in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I work in Android Studio 1.0 RC 2 and I have an Android Emulator with Intel HAXM. The emulator is running normally. It shows the hardware buttons, but this buttons is not clickable. The AVD configuration is default for Nexus S, but it's scale is 0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @CommonsWare comment

> @Plugie: I never use those skins, and I am not aware that those buttons are ever supposed to be clickable.

I recommend to set hw.mainKeys=no

> Go into the actual configuration file for your AVD. On OS X and Linux, that normally is ~/.android/avd/.../config.ini, where ... is based on the name of your AVD. See what your hw.mainKeys value is

After set hw.mainKeys=no, it will show System Bar which can be seen in screen shoot which red rectangle. Then you can navigate BACK, HOME using System Bar instead of Hardware Button

[image: nexus s with hw.mainKeys=no]

Answer (score 5):

> It shows the hardware buttons, but this buttons is not clickable

If it shows HOME and BACK in the navigation bar, then they are not "the hardware buttons". That is the navigation bar. For actual "hardware" HOME and BACK buttons, you should not see anything, and the are mapped to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> respectively on your development machine's keyboard.

Go into the actual configuration file for your AVD. On OS X and Linux, that normally is `~/.android/avd/.../config.ini`, where `...` is based on the name of your AVD. See what your `hw.mainKeys` value is. For "hardware" HOME and BACK buttons, `hw.mainKeys` should be `yes`; for a navigation bar with HOME and BACK buttons, `hw.mainKeys` should be `no`.

Comment: It shows hardware button. Using Nexus S as skin. The sreen shoot can be shown in [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92270102/nexus%20s.PNG. Already checked config.ini and make sure hw.mainKeys=yes. But the hardware button (red square in screen shoot) can't be clicked

Comment: @Plugie: I never use those skins, and I am not aware that those buttons are ever supposed to be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to change some of your emulator settings in order to do that. Change the skin to 'Skin with dynamic hardware controls' and make sure the 'hardware keyboard present' checkbox is checked.  Not sure if this is the solution, but give it a try.

Comment: I saw emulator configuration, in it there are only device's skins and variant "no skin", there are not variant " with hardware dynamic controls ". Checkbox "hardware keyboard present" is checked. Are there more variants of the solution?

Comment: Sorry, i am out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

For me it required a little more work. In short, avd creates android image incorrectly, setting dPad and mainKey to "no". This post helped 
http://ridz1ba.blogspot.ru/2012/12/android-virtual-devices-avd-problem-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the emulator of Lollipop or Jellybean doesn't auto update the display (tested on Chipmunk) so pressing any buttons will look like they are not clickable unless you refresh the display by clicking other tabs such as Device Manager. I run Marshmallow (x86_64 Google APIs on Chipmunk) and all buttons respond to click.