# How to show virtual button in Design view of Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my layout in Design view of Android studio, when Pixel device is selected.
[image]

But when I switch the device to AVD device such as 4_WVGA_Nexus_S.., the virtual button is disappear.
[image]

How can I bring it back?

This is my AVD device show :
[image]

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252308/hardware-buttons-is-not-clickable-in-android-emulator ?

Comment: @Martheen Sorry but this is in Design view. I try to open another project and it hardly appears. I don't know for what reason

Comment: If the Design view device options follow what's offered by AVD, I'd assume it will also follow what AVD define for each device (ie, whether a device have hardware keys or require onscreen keys)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243746/how-to-use-a-custom-resolution-in-android-studios-layout-editor or you can just add a new resolution and include other settings there

Answer (score 0):

Choose View Options (eye symbol) -> Show System UI

Comment: The System UI is already checked. See at : https://imgur.com/OHPI0q3